# Identity server logging details

Tags: identityserver3

I am using serilog for logging in Identity Server 3 and messages are formatted like below.

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                 .WriteTo.Trace(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:MM} [{Level}] ({Name:l}){NewLine} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                 .CreateLogger();
```

I see few extra lines of logs like below

> iisexpress.exe Warning: 0 :

General log looks like this

> 16:05 [Information] (IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretParser) 
>   Secret id found: "abc"

What are these logs. which code in identity server is logging this?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer uses LibLog, which will output to several popular logging frameworks including SeriLog. [Here is the documentation on how to configure logging in IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html)